# GUI tool for ruby on rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface

I am trying to design UI for a web application (Ruby on Rails). I need a gui tool like Dreamweaver, but something that is free. Could anyone suggest a GUI drag and drop tool for ruby on rails application?

Comment: What are you looking to "drag and drop"?

Comment: Nothing like that exists yet. With Rails you get a closer glimpse at the edge of information architecture. If you're looking for "drag and drop", you will have to stretch back a few years of code innovation to exactly what Dreamweaver offers. A drag and drop GUI based off of things we figured out on the frontline fifteen years ago and made easy for everyone to use.

Comment: Just to do drag and drop design with controllers and models

Comment: Though I've never used it, I hear RubyMine tries to consolidate the whole RubyRails experience. But with all due respect, your either way out of your league, or approaching your goals the wrong way. The **best** way to learn this level of coding is to learn it the right away, and start from scratch, start with basic tutorials on getting set up and work from there. You won't find a GUI set up for that. Even objective-c with iPhone programming has a beautiful array of GUI tools to use but still its just the tip of the iceberg to what is required to produce that kind of software.

Comment: I hate to say this, but if you want to develop code with a GUI, you might be better off with one of the .NET languages. Rails is not a very good framework for IDE development since it is so dynamic and constantly evolving. Having said that, I strongly encourage you to give Rails a chance w/out a GUI. http://railsforzombies.com/ is a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks all for posting the information. A little disappointed that there isn't a standard GUI tool for Ruby on Rails applications. But will look into the links that you guys posted here.

Comment: I appreciate what Rubyuser is getting at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want does not exist. Just take some time and learn a little Ruby, then Rails. Once you kind of know whats going on you won't need a GUI IDE. I'm a former Flash ActionScript guy who "had' to have a GUI IDE to do anything. Now, its Sublime Text 2 and Git all the way. I love it. I'm even learning some Vim.

Many people like IDE's with GUI's vs. that "blank" page feel of TextMate, Sublime Text, etc... That's just because they don't know what to do. Once you learn some Ruby, then Rails you will be fine.

I say learn a little Ruby first, so that you will know what's going on when you look at Rails code. If you don't know some Ruby, you will feel the same way about Rails as you do about using a "non" GUI IDE, you'll be confused. Pragmatic Studio's Ruby course and Skillshare's One Month Rails are two great and affordable ways to get started.

1. Learn Ruby Basics - http://pragmaticstudio.com/ruby
2. Learn Some Beginning Rails - http://onemonthrails.com/
3. Learn Intermediate Rails - http://pragmaticstudio.com/rails

These courses altogether cost less than $450.00 USD and can be completed in less than two months. Once you take these courses and use Sublime Text, TextMate, Vim, etc... you'll be able to start building GUIs and web applications in Ruby and have a good start programming in other languages. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

PLEASE  Do not design in a GUI.  Use a text editor or IDE like sublimetext 2 or Ruby Mine. Unless you want that editor to inject a bunch of useless markup.